# Connect to BLE device and send/read data via NSNetService on iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, nsnetservice, nsnetservicebrowser

I have an iPhone app which communicates with external device via `NSNetService`. 
Now I want to add support for bluetooth.
So I would like to discover and connect to device via bluetooth (BLE) and when connected I would like to send/receive data via `NSNetService`, so I reuse existing code...

Is this possible on iOS7+? Any example/hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSNetService uses TCP/IP and multicast DNS.  Bluetooth Low Energy does not implement a TCP/IP network and so NSNetService cannot be applied to BLE connections.